# PHP: using var_export with extended classes?

Tags: php, class, oop

In PHP I'm trying to use `var_export` but I cannot get it to work with an extended class:

```
class BaseClass {
    public $a = 1;

    public static function __set_state($array) {
      //is it possible to get the classname of the extended class here?
      $obj = new BaseClass();

      foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $obj->$k = $v;
      }

      return $obj;
    }
}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
    public $b = 2;
}

$object = new ExtendedClass();

var_dump($object);

$serialized_object = var_export($object, true);
eval('$object2 = ' . $serialized_object. ';'); 

echo "<br/>";
var_dump($object2);
```

$object2 will then be of class `BaseClass` instead of `ExtendedClass` !

I have a few thousand classes that extend from a base class, so making a `__set_state` method for every class is not really an option.

Is it somehow possible in `__set_state` to get the classname of the extended class ?

Comment: You really should use serialize() and unserialize() rather than var_export() and eval(). Using eval like that is terrible practice.

Comment: I tried serialize on an array of objects but I found it very hard to get the exact same array of objects back after unserializing, so I tried var_export instead...

Comment: @Dylan: Try implementing [this interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) in your base class, then use serialize/unserialize...

Comment: @One_Trick_Pony : I'll look into this... How do I retrieve all properties of the extended classes in the serialize/unserialize methods of the base class then?

Comment: Here's an example: http://codepad.org/1NHbXHdR

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the called class:

```
$obj = new static();
```

instead of

```
$obj = new BaseClass();
```

Comment: yes it works !  Never heard of that before, do you have some documentation somewhere on this?